# R package called from python - Error

Tags: r, python-2.7, apriori

I am trying to call R packages from python (python 2.7.9) and trying to call Apriori function.

```
import rpy2
from rpy2 import *
import rpy2.interactive as r
arules = r.packages.importr("arules")

from rpy2.robjects.vectors import ListVector

od = r.OrderedDict()
od["supp"] = 0.0005
od["conf"] = 0.7
od["target"] = 'rules'

result = ListVector(od)

dataset = 'c:/Apriori/testcase.txt'

my_rules = arules.apriori(dataset, parameter=result)

print('my_rules',my_rules)
```

I am failing in rules. The error is below:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'packages'

Please help

Comment: This worked. Thanks..But it failed with " RRuntimeError: Error in as(data, "transactions") : 
  no method or default for coercing "character" to "transactions" on the below line my_rules = arules.apriori(dataset, parameter=result)

Comment: As the error message hints at it, `dataset` is currently a string while it should be an R object of the kind the function `apriori()` can handle...

Answer (score 0):

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
arules = importr("arules")
```

Comment: Hi , thanks.this part worked..But it failed in another line  my_rules = arules.apriori(dataset, parameter=result)  The error is  " RRuntimeError: Error in as(data, "transactions") : no method or default for coercing "character" to "transactions" . Please help